# How to count zeros in each column using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to count zeros in a dataframe.

To count NAs I'm using

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum(is.na(.))))
```

that returns

```
# A tibble: 3 × 11
    cyl   mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
  <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     4     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
2     6     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
3     8     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

How can I do something like

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum(identical(.,0)))
```

to achieve the same result but counting zeros instead of NAs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

because the `.` will be a vector in this case you can just use a logical test and `sum` because `TRUE` is treated as a 1 and `FALSE` is a 0.

```
mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    summarise_each(funs(sum(.==0)))

    cyl   mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
  (dbl) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int)
1     4     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     3     0     0
2     6     0     0     0     0     0     0     3     4     0     0
3     8     0     0     0     0     0     0    14    12     0     0
```

Comment: Eventually `summarise_each` is going to be deprecated in favor of `summarise_all`, but it's a drop-in replacement here.

Answer (score 5):

We can also do this in `base R`

```
aggregate(.~cyl, mtcars, FUN = function(x) sum(x==0))
#  cyl mpg disp hp drat wt qsec vs am gear carb
#1   4   0    0  0    0  0    0  1  3    0    0
#2   6   0    0  0    0  0    0  3  4    0    0
#3   8   0    0  0    0  0    0 14 12    0    0
```

Or with `rowsum`

```
rowsum(+(mtcars[-2]==0), group = mtcars$cyl)
#     mpg disp hp drat wt qsec vs am gear carb
#4   0    0  0    0  0    0  1  3    0    0
#6   0    0  0    0  0    0  3  4    0    0
#8   0    0  0    0  0    0 14 12    0    0
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mtcars)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x==0)) , cyl]
```